# how to load page faster whenever we need to load many facebook widget and twitter like widget on the single page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a webpage where we need to show facebook like or twitter like many time. i found that it's goes in size 2.3 MB

so i thing that how i can load them after page load ?

any suggestion to do this in jQuery html

Answer (score 1):

I would load one Javascript code for Facebook or Twitter than call it each time you need it